# Exponential generating function for number of 10 length sequences built from the alphabet, with some restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, generating-functions

I've got the following homework question. If anybody could possibly point me in the right direction, that would be great:

> Suppose X is a sequence with 10 terms built from 26 letters {a, b, c, ..., z} such that e, n, r, and s occur at least once. Please determine with proof the number of such Xs.

I'm looking to create an exponential generating function to solve this problem. From what I understand, if ALL 26 letters had to occur at least once, the exponential generating function could be described as $ (e^x-1)^{26}$.

Since there are $4$ values that must occur at least once, my assumption is that the generating function will be $$(e^x-1)^4(e^x)^{22}$$

And then to find the actual answer, I believe I will need the coefficient on $$\frac{x^{10}}{10!}$$

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Now multiply out and get the coefficients.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I've had a bit of trouble grasping the concept of EGF's, so confirmation that I'm doing this right is really helpful.

Comment: Take a peek at [analytic combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_combinatorics), or at Segdewick and Flajolet's ["Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms"](http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu), check out the basic proofs for labelled structures. I believe this will clarify the mess (and give you tools to solve all sorts of hairy problems in a few lines).